# I want to make an object from another object with some properties from it

Tags: javascript

```
let newResult = {};
result.forEach(info => {
  for(const item in info){
    if(info[item].toLowerCase() == value){
      newResult.item = info[item];
    }
  }
})

console.log(newResult)
```

I want to make an object from another object and for this reason, this item should be dynamic instead of a static string. Any help?

Comment: Could you add the code snippet and delete the image link please?
You can do that through surrounding your code with ``` ```

Comment: *"Any help?"* - Help with **what**, specifically?  In what way does your code not work as expected?

Comment: Can we have a look at the object structure please? also the result of the `console.log()` and the result you need. We will be able to provide with the solution then.